# whats easier to program in for newbies - directx 12 or vulkan

Tags: c++, directx, vulkan

I'm new to computer graphics and game development, and wanted to know whats easier to learn - Directx 12 or Vulkan?

By easier I'm referring to function names, class names, naming conventions, how to setup/initiate a vulkan project vs directx 12 etc etc.

Comment: "*By easier I'm referring to function names, class names, naming conventions, how to setup/initiate a vulkan project vs directx 12 etc etc.*" For people who are both interested in and *capable of* using either API, those are *trivialities*. If you can't download and compile a simple library, you're not at the point in your programing journey to be able to handle the complexities of actually using either API. Things like naming conventions are irrelevant next to the task of actually understanding all of the complexities of the behavior of these APIs.

Comment: Since Directx 12 is a Microsoft technology I would expect it to be needlessly complex compared to a cross platform library like Vulkan. They tend to overengineer things, e.g. optimistici generalization with a zillion parameters for something that can only be done with one single particular magic combination of parameter values. Disclaimer: at most I have only dabbled a little in DirectX, I can't remember, and I've certainly not ever used Vulcan.

Comment: I'd say they are very similar APIs. On the other hand, DirectX 9-10-11 has a good API while OpenGL's is comparably unusable. The's an old adage that you have to learn DirectX before OpenGL, but the same's true for DirectX12 and Vulkan. Learn DirectX11 before anything else

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Neither is an appropriate API for a newbie. Both APIs expose the application programmer to the intimate details of the GPU, making you fully responsible for synchronization in a 'lock-free' style, memory management including all edge-cases such as low-resource scenarios, fully described state, etc. These APIs are intended for expert graphics programmers who essentially want to talk directly to the video driver with some level of vendor-neutral abstraction.

> Graphics programming is already a challenging discipline particularly when it comes to debugging. You can mess up a single number in a thousand lines of code and end up with a blank screen and have to work out what went wrong. It's particularly challenging to debug in context with GPU shader programming once you move beyond trivial shaders. With Direct3D 12/Vulkan, you can multiply the challenges even further with driver crashes that stop your application, timing-based synchronization issues that change based on even tiny differences in variables, or worse it works perfectly fine unless you use a different screen resolution or completely fails on a different PC.

Direct3D 11 is a good API for learning graphics programming and game development on the Windows platform. Direct3D 9 is only applicable to legacy systems or emerging markets which tend to have very specific and idiosyncratic hardware requirements. All modern Windows platforms support Direct3D 11 including Universal Windows Platform (UWP); Windows Win32 desktop apps on Windows 7, 8.1, or 10; and Xbox One. If you are interested, I suggest taking a look at the [DirectX Tool Kit for DirectX 11](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started).

> **UPDATE** DirectXTK is also a good place to start because once you have learned it on DirectX 11, you can transition over to the [DirectX 12](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK12/wiki/Getting-Started) version and have a leg-up on the basics.

You can certainly learn the basics of graphics programming and game development on other platforms, but I can't speak to the best options there. One thing I can suggest is that you decide if your passion is really **game development** or **graphics programming**. You may not know enough right now to really judge fully, but these are distinct paths in the industry. If you have a game vision you want to make, then look at something like Unity or Unreal Engine so you can focus on *game development* aspects. If you are more interested in graphics or game-related technology (audio and media, engines, simulations, real-time interactive behvaior, etc.) in general, then learning Direct3D 11 is as good a place to start as any.

Comment: thanks chuck, this was very informative and precisely what the answer I was looking for atleast in terms of comparison of the two for newbie game/graphics developer.  Thanks again.

Comment: If you are planning to learn either one then it's better to pick Vulkan instead, because it supports other platforms too. Stick with Direct3D and you will be chained to Microsoft's platform.